# Finding geodesics of a surface

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geodesic

[image]

[image]

I'm not able to understand how the answer given above has been obtained. How did they deduce the sigma is isometric to the plane? 
Also, if a surface is isometric to another surface then does that mean they have the same first fundamental form and the same second fundamental form?
Also, if a surface is isometric to another surface then is it true that they will have the same geodesics?

How else in general do we find the geodesics of a surface?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So let $S$ be the surface. There is a parametrization of $S$, let $\phi :\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\sigma$ being its restriction to $(0,1)\times (0,1)$. Note that the image of $\phi$ is $S$.

The surface $S$ has the same first fundamental form as the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ which implies that they are locally isometric. Moreover $\sigma$ is differentiable. 
So we have a differentiable map that is a local isometry with $\mathbb{R}^2$ complete, connected riemannian manifold and $S$ connected riemannian manifold. 
This implies that they are isometric. See [How to go from local to global isometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116195/how-to-go-from-local-to-global-isometry).

--

Regarding the question about geodesics of isometric surfaces: If $\phi: M\rightarrow N$ is an isometry between two surfaces then the image of a geodesic in $M$, is a geodesic in $N$. They are not the same though.