# Is an isometry a diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

It seems that isometry does not have to be bijective (surjective) as I learnt from my lecture. But why on
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry_(Riemannian_geometry)
defined isometry as diffeomorphism? So it is bijective? A bit confusing.

Which is right?

Comment: Wikipedia is right. Do you have a precise statement of what your lecturer said?

Comment: @gj255 The embedding $P:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ with $P(x) = (x_1,x_2,0)$ is an isometric embedding. It is not surjective. Maybe, one strictly distinguishes between an **isometry** and an **isometric embedding**. This could be the source of confusion.

Comment: Or even here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry section: Formal definitions. it seems that they attribute "bijective" to isometry, so there can be a non-bijective?

Comment: Well here, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Isometry.html they define it as bijective... really confusing..

Comment: Your link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry is informative with respect to your question. There they say _"usually assumed to be bijective"_. This already implies that there are different versions in use. I recommend sticking to the version of your teacher and keeping in mind that there might be a different version in literature.

Comment: If $M$ is a _complete_, connected Riemannian manifold and $N$ is connected, then a local isometry $f:M \to N$ is bijective: [How to go from local to global isometry](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116195). Without completeness of $M$, you have examples such as $x \mapsto x + 1$ on the set of positive reals.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: You need simply connected target not just connected.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: Whoops...yes, thank you.